# Transcribe audio from live stream

Tags: google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to transcribe audio from a live audio stream using this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

I was able to get it to work with a microphone, but I'm wondering if it could be used to transcribe live internet audio streams. Is this possible, and are there any good resources on how to do this?